# Error in mapper when using parameter name

Tags: java, mybatis

I am using Spring 3.2.0 MVC with mybatis 3.2.3 and mybatis-spring 1.2.1 with ojdbc6 11.2.0.2.0

I have an XML mapper defined with 2 parameters of different types (date and integer).
I reference them in the query as #{myid} and #{mydate} but I get an error from ibatis:

```
org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'myid' not found. Available parameters are [1, 0, param1, param2]
```

If I reference the parameters as #{0} and #{1} everything works fine.

I have a another mapper with only a single parameter and I am able to reference the parameter as #{myDate} (the only difference is that I have the following in the XML:

```
<select id="getAllbyDate" parameterType="date" resultType="com.test.myTest">
```

My problem is that the query with multiple parameters does not allow me to specify the parameter name in the XML file.  I am able to reference by name with a single parameter.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In mapper Interface java file write the method like this

```
public List<com.test.myTest> getAllbyDate(@Param("date") Date date, @Param("myid") int myid)
```

Then, modify xml file

```
<select id="getAllbyDate" parameterType="map" resultType="com.test.myTest">
```

Mybatis put all parameters with annotation `@Param` into map.

Comment: Could it be parameter name specified in XML (not with @Param annotation in code)?

Comment: Should only work with `@org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param` and not with `@org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param`.